# Sample with stratify category

Tags: python, database, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I have a collection with 1 million pieces of data.

In the documents there are two fields:

- a string which can take 10 values (let's call it A)
- a int (Let's call it B)

I'd like to have a sample with 25% of the data which respects these two rules:

1 - A should have the same distribution in the sample than in the original collection

2 - For this specific distribution, choose the data with the greater B

Comment: Wouldn't this have a trivial solution? Group data by A, for each group sort the data with descending B and take the top 25%. Not sure how your data is organized so its impossible to provide relevant code.

Comment: that makes sense, thx ! (I'm ready to wait a long time ^^ )